# Why Bigquery TIMESTAMP_TRUNC function is having such behavior when using timezones?

Tags: google-bigquery, timezone

Is there anyone who can explain this behavior :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T", '2022-12-17 23:50:50.000000 UTC')), DAY, "UTC-1") --2022-12-17 01:00:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T", '2022-12-17 23:50:50.000000 UTC')), DAY, "UTC") --2022-12-17 00:00:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T", '2022-12-17 23:50:50.000000 UTC')), DAY, "UTC+1") --2022-12-17 23:00:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T", '2022-12-17 23:50:50.000000 UTC')), DAY, "UTC+2") --2022-12-17 22:00:00 UTC
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T", '2022-12-17 23:50:50.000000 UTC+2')), DAY, "UTC+2") --2022-12-16 22:00:00 UTC
```

It seems that google does not provide enough explanation or examples to get this straight.
My questions are :

1. what is the use of the timezone as argument in TIMESTAMP_TRUNC if it
   can be specified in the timestamp expression itself.
2. if would be great if someone details their explanation with what the
   timezone in the timestamp value means, the timezone as 3rd argument
   in the TIMESTAMP_TRUNC function means, and the UTC in the result
   means

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of my collegue here is an explanation of what is happening when using TIMESTAMP_TRUNC:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%F %T", '2022-12-17 23:50:50.000000 UTC')), DAY, "UTC+1") --2022-12-17 23:00:00 UTC
```

1. ask yourself this question : what is its equivalent in UTC+1 ( third argument) ? => '2022-12-18 00:50:50 UTC+1'
2. truncate at day level (result will be in UTC+1) '2022-12-18 00:00:00 UTC+1'
3. ask yourself this question : what is its equivalent in UTC ? => '2022-12-17 23:00:00 UTC

It may seem obvious for you but if someone gets stuck with it one day I hope they this will help